# Solving differential equation with infinite series sum

Tags: calculus, summation, power-series, infinity

We are given the following differential equation,

$$x \cdot \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + (2+x)\frac{dy}{dx}+y=0$$

i) Show the following,

$$x \cdot \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + (2+x)\frac{dy}{dx}+y=\sum{[(n+1)c_n+(n+1)(n+2)c_{n+1}]x^n}$$

ii) Explain that if the power series $\sum{c_nx^n}$ satisfies the differential equation, then

$$c_{n+1}=-\frac{1}{n+2}c_n$$

iii) Determine using the solution from (ii), the radius of convergence for an arbitrary power series solution to the differential equation. [Hint: Hint: use ratio test to examine cn + 1 / cn for n → ∞. It is not necessary to calculate the coefficients $c_n$.]

**My Working**

P.s the riemann sum is from n=0 to infinity in part (i) after the equalsign.

For i)

I know that I have to use the power series,
$$y=\sum _{ n=0 }^{ \infty  }{c_n·x^n  } $$

Therefore,
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{nc_n·x^{n-1}  }$$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\sum _{ n=2 }^{ \infty  }{n(n-1)c_nx^{n-2}  }$$

Now it is only the solution, if
$$x \cdot \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + (2+x)\frac{dy}{dx}+y=0$$
$$x \sum _{ n=2 }^{ \infty  }{n(n-1)c_nx^{n-2}  } + (2+x)\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{nc_n·x^{n-1}  }+\sum _{ n=0 }^{ \infty  }{c_n·x^n  }=0$$

Which becomes,
$$\sum _{ n=2 }^{ \infty  }{n(n-1)c_nx^{n-1}  } + \sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{2nc_n·x^{n-1}  }+\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{nc_n·x^{n}  }+\sum _{ n=0 }^{ \infty  }{c_n·x^n  }=0$$

Then I changed the limits on my sums so that everything is starting from n=0, and I ended up with the following expression,

$$\sum _{ n=2 }^{ \infty  }{n(n-1)c_nx^{n-1}  } + \sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{2nc_n·x^{n-1}  }+\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{nc_n·x^{n}  }+\sum _{ n=0 }^{ \infty  }{c_n·x^n  }=0$$

$$3c_1 +\sum _{ n=0 }^{ \infty  }{ [(n+2)(n+1) c_{n+2} x^{n+1}+2c_{n+2} (n+2) x^{n+1}+(n+2) c_{n+2} x^{n+2}+c_n x^n } $$

Where ofcourse $c_1=0$ and now I can not factorise it either, because the power on x is not the same and I can not understand how to get to the answer.

**Part ii)**

I have solved part (ii) by saying the following,
$$(n+1)c_n+(n+1)(n+2)c_{n+1}=0$$

Hence solving we come cross to the following,

$$c_{n+1}=-\frac{1}{n+2}c_n$$

**Part iii)**

This part I do not understand. Isnt convergence the limit value for $x$? Meaning that the convergence radius is just the value such that,
$$ x∈[-\rho, \rho]$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation that you have derived while performing the series solution, as you have stated is:

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} n (n-1)c_n x^{n-1} +  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2nc_n x^{n-1} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nc_n x^{n} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n x^{n}=0$$

Which is exactly the same as the one below:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n (n-1)c_n x^{n-1} +  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2nc_n x^{n-1} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} nc_n x^{n} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n x^{n}=0$$

Since the terms you obtain by putting $n=0,1$ in the above series expansions are all zero.

And finally the above set of equation can be re-stated as follows:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n (n+1)c_{n+1} x^{n} +  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2(n+1)c_{n+1} x^{n} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} nc_n x^{n} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n x^{n}=0$$

And now you can take  $x^n $ common from all the series and find the relation stated in (i).

Again as for the radius of convergence,  $$R=\lim_\limits {n\to\infty} |\frac {c_n}{c_{n+1}}|=\lim_\limits {n\to\infty} |(n+2)|= \infty$$

Comment: Glad to see that some ones do not shift index !!

Comment: Thank you very much :) Does that mean that the radius of convergence is simply [-infinity, infinity]?